# NullPointerException on adding strings to TreeSet<String>

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, set, bufferedreader, treeset

My problem is that I can't find mistake in this code. I want to fill  a field of my program(Set of strings) in constructor with Strings readen from a file.

`

```
public AnagramUserInput(){
    Set<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> lexic = new TreeSet<String>();
    File lexicon = new File("C:/Users/Konstanty Orzeszko/Desktop/do testu/english_words_WIN.txt");
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lexicon));
        String word;

        while(((word = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            this.lexic.add(word);//Exception is throwned right in this line
         }
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }
}`
```

Could you tell me what is wrong/how to fix it?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you sure the file is opened properly?

Comment: Do you have another variable named `lexic` at class level? If so you're shadowing that variable, which would explain the `NPE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.lexic` is evaluated to `null`. Note that `this.lexis` doesn't point to the constructor's local `lexic` variable, but to the instance's one.

*If you want to* add the String to the constructor's `lexic` variable, just get rid of the `this` keyword:

```
lexic.add(word);
```

Comment: Just to add, br.close() should be kept in finally.

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you have another variable named `lexic` as a class instance variable. (The above code would not compile if this is not the case)

Therefore its likely you're shadowing the `result` variable. Replace

```
Set<String> lexic = new TreeSet<String>();
```

with

```
lexic = new TreeSet<String>();
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see here is

```
this.lexic.add(word); // this.lexic
```

Remove the `this`. Because the constructor instantiates the class. Even before the object is created, you're tryin to use `this`, which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
this.lexic.add(word);
```

You are using this in constructor, that means, you are using the object during its creation. That is why you get NPE. remove this, it will work.

if you put filling part in a method also, that means

```
Set<String> lexic = new TreeSet<String>();
```

is also in same method, then also "this" will not work because "this" is not for local level variable. But in that case also, it will not give NPE but compiler error.

This code is working fine, you can check once :

```
public AnagramUserInput()
{
    Set<String> result = new TreeSet<String>();
    Set<String> lexic = new TreeSet<String>();
    File lexicon = new File("output.txt");
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(lexicon));
        String word;

        while(((word = br.readLine()) != null)) {
            lexic.add(word);//Exception is throwned right in this line
         }

    }catch(IOException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc.toString());
        System.exit(1);
    }

    finally
    {
       if (br != null)
       {
            try
            {
                br.close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }

    System.out.println(lexic);
}
```

just make sure, file is on proper location as required.

Comment: I remove the filling part from constructor, put it into different method, and call it on created object in main(), it still gives the same error.

Comment: Edited my answer, you can refer once.